# Expressing 2N point DFT in terms of N point DFT

Tags: dft, homework, exam

I have a problem with expressing odd samples of X2 in terms of X1. I understand that the resulting DFT will be more precise in terms of expressing the exact spectrum of signal x[n], due to more samples. Moreover I know that even samples of X2(k) are copy of the spectrum of X1(k), however I do not know how to mathematically compute the odd ones.

The task is as follows:

Let $x[n]$  be  a  periodic  sequence  with  period $N_1$ .   Thus $x[n]$  is  also  periodic  for  period $N_2 =  2 N_1$ .   We  may compute $X_1[k]$:  $N$-point DFT of $x[n]$ and $X_2[k]$:  $2N$-point DFT of $x[n]$.

- Express $X_2$in terms of $X_1$ Hint: it is easy with even samples $X_2[2m]$ , harder with odd ones $X2_[2m+ 1]$ , for $m$ integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider N-point sequence $x[n]$ whose N-point DFT is $X[k]$. To compute 2N-point DFT, $X_2[k]$, of $x[n]$, one should append N-zeroes to $x[n]$, and make it a 2N-point sequence, denoted $x_2[n]$. Obviously, first N-samples of $x[n]$ and $x_2[n]$ are identical, and last N-samples of $x_2[n]$ are just zeroes.

Write 2N-point DFT of $x_2[n]$:

$$ X_2[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{2N-1} x_2[n] e^{-j  \frac{2 \pi}{2N} n k } ~~,~~ k=0,1,...,2N-1 \tag{1}$$

which is identical to:
$$ X_2[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] e^{-j  \frac{2 \pi}{N} n (k/2)  } ~~,~~ k=0,1,...,2N-1 \tag{2}$$

Now, the **even** indexed samples of $X_2[k]$ can be shown to be $X[k/2]$, by setting $k_e=2m$ in Eq.2,  $m=0,1,...,N-1$ :

$$ X_2[2m] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] e^{-j  \frac{2 \pi}{N} n (2m/2)  }  = X[m]  \tag{3}$$

The **odd** indexed samples of $X_2[k]$ can also be obtained similarly by setting $k_o = 2m+1$, in Eq.2:

$$ X_2[2m+1] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] e^{-j  \frac{2 \pi}{N} n (\frac{2m+1}{2}) }  = X[m+0.5] \tag{4}$$

Eq.4 is an **interpolation** statement; i.e., the sample $X[m+0.5]$ implies (but does not perform) interpolation between $X[m]$ and $X[m+1]$. However, it's not proper to set $k=m+0.5$ into the argument of a *sequence*, which is a mathematical array of numbers indexed by an integer; fractional indices make **no literal sense**. Nevertheless, Eq.4 means that taking 2N-point DFT of an N-point sequence, effectively, interpolates between samples of N-point DFT of the N-point sequence.

On the other hand, one can manipulate Eq.4 to see that:

$$ X_2[2m+1] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] e^{-j  \frac{2 \pi}{N} n (\frac{2m+1}{2}) }  = X[m+0.5] \tag{5}$$

$$ X_2[2m+1] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] e^{-j \frac{ \pi}{N} n} e^{-j  \frac{2 \pi}{N} n m }  \tag{6}$$

denoting $x_o[n] = x[n] e^{-j \frac{ \pi}{N} n}$ yields
$$ X_2[2m+1] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_o[n] e^{-j  \frac{2 \pi}{N} n m}  = X_o[m]\tag{7}$$

Where $X_o[m]$ is the N-point DFT of the sequence $x_o[n]$. Time-domain modulation of $x[n]$ by $ e^{-j \frac{ \pi}{N} n}$, performs half-sample shift of its N-point DFT $X[k]$, thus describe the so called interpolated values $X[k+0.5]$.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about the shift in time property of DFT for solving this one.

Comment: Can you explain why we use here $$e^{-j\frac{\pi}{N}n}$$ and not $$e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}n}$$?

Comment: By elaborating on the DFT expression you can get it...