# Inserting zeros: effect on DFT

Tags: discrete-signals, dft, homework

Let N be an even integer, and $x[n]$ be a finite length signal over the interval $n\in [0,N-1]$; let $X[k]$ be the N-pt DFT of $x[n]$.

Find the 2N-Pt DFT of $x_1[n]$ in terms of $x[n]$, where:

$$x_1[n] = \begin{cases}
            x[\frac{n}{2}], &         \text{if } n  \text{ is even}\\
            0      &          \text{else}     
    \end{cases}
$$

Now, the idea I had in mind was to write out the DFT sum and then change the summing variable $n\rightarrow 2n$ but that doesn't work:

$$X_1(k) = \sum_{n=0}^{2N-1} x[n/2]e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{2N}nk} $$

$$\downarrow n \text{ to } 2n$$

$$X_1(k) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1/2} x[n]e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}nk} \neq X(k)$$

This doesn't work for two reasons, 1) The form of the DFT is not correct and 2) the fact that $x_1[n] = x[n/2]$ for only even $n$'s is not reflected in the sum!

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close. We have

$$\begin{align}X_1[k]&=\sum_{{n=0,\;n\textrm{ even}}}^{2N-1}x[n/2]e^{-j\frac{2\pi} {2N}nk}\\&=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n]e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}nk}\\&=X[k],\qquad k=0,1,\ldots, 2N-1\end{align}$$

Naturally, the DFTs of $x[n]$ and $x_1[n]$ have the same values. The only difference is that $X_1[k]$ has length $2N$, i.e., the values of $X[k]$ are simply repeated. This is what upsampling (insertion of zeros) does: the period in the other domain is multiplied by the number of inserted zeros plus $1$, i.e., one inserted zero results in twice the period, two zeros result in three times the period, etc.

The dual problem (concatenating two periods in the sample domain) was discussed in [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/87289/4298).

Comment: So basically $X_1(k)$ is just two periods of $X(k)$. This is a cool result!

Comment: Matt, it's the fencepost or telephone pole kinda issue.  But if you have valid values for $$X_1[k] \qquad\forall \  k\in\mathbb{Z} \ \ 0 \le k \le 2N-1$$ isn't the length of $X_1[k]$ equal to $2N$?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Yes, $X_1[k]$ has $2N$ values. Was there any misunderstanding about this?

Comment: I wouldn't call it length $2N-1$, that's all.    I think that might lead to a misunderstanding.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Oh, I see now that you've edited out my $2N-1$. I meant to write $2N$, it was just a silly mistake. Thx for editing.