# N-point DFT of window function

Tags: fft, dft, window-functions

I am currently choosing a window function to analyze signals in frequency domain. While I understand the reasoning behind using a window function and what to look for concerning main lobe and side lobe forms, I have stumbled across the fact that the frequency domain representation of a window function that Matlab generates with the `wvtool` looks a lot different to what I can obtain from simply applying the `fft` command to my respective window function.

After some research, I now understand that the shape of the window function in frequency domain depends on how many points the `fft` command uses. E.g. when applying the `fft` command with 100 points to a window of length `n=100`, the result is a continuous curve. The more points I use for the `fft`, the more accurately the lobes start to form that are also visible in the `wvtool`.

I have also read [in this Stack Exchange question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/53621/expressing-2n-point-dft-in-terms-of-n-point-dft) that an `fft` with more points than the signal length `n` basically interpolates between the samples of the `n-point fft` and that every second point of a `2n-point fft` coincides with the `n-point fft`.

So, **can I assume that the `2n-point fft` is more accurate than the n-point fft? And how would that be** considering that the `2n-point fft` is just created from adding n zeros to the original signal and therefore doesn't add meaningful information to the signal? And when applying ffts to signals that are not window functions: **Am I generally better off just adding more points to the fft?** Normally, to increase frequency resolution, I would perform an `n-point fft` over a larger sample size `n`. But no matter how large the sample size, I can never obtain the lobes of the window functions without performing an `fft` with more points than samples. So am I somehow missing information when performing only an `n-point fft` on a real-world signal?

Thanks for any help, the more I research this the more I am confused at the moment.

I have added a **minimal code sample** to better illustrate what I mean. `ws` is the window size and `m` is a factor to increase `fft` points. So e.g. use `m=2` to perform a `2n-point fft`.

```
ws = 1000;
m = 1;

hanning = abs(fft(hann(ws), m * ws)) / sum(hann(ws));
hanning = hanning / max(hanning);
hanning = hanning(1:ws/2+1);

f = (0:(1/m):(ws/(2*m)));
f = f';

figure;
plot(f, 20*log10(hanning));
```

Comment: maybe you need to zero-pad the window function (making it longer and requiring a larger $N$ for the FFT) before the FFT.

Comment: As far as I understand that is exactly what a 2n-point fft does, adding n zeros to the window function and then performing a normal fft. I'm interested in why this leads to the (better?) result.

Comment: You should be careful using "`hanning`" as a symbol in your MATLAB code because MATLAB uses that for the Hann window.  Sorta like redefining `pi`.

Comment: I don't see any zero-padding in the code.  Maybe if `m=2` but it's not.  Remember that the FFT (which is a fast DFT) periodically extends the data presented to it.  So which is closer to reality?  A window function that is repeated right away with copies or a window function separated by some zeros.  Because in the continuous-time real life, that window function is supposed to be isolated with zeros on both sides extending forever.

Comment: It’s a good question. You’re basically wondering about *frequency resolution*, which is the minimum distance between two frequency components the dft can resolve, and *frequency precision*, which is simply the distance between two dft bins. Please see [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/84178/63763) which might help understand the difference between the two.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: If I increase m, the side lobes start to show, yes.

Comment: @Jdip: So increasing the window size either by padding or by using more measurement samples would increase frequency precision, which is easily calculable from the window size. From applying ffts to sine signals I found that an increase in frequency precision also comes with an increase in resolution. But the latter then depends on the exact form of the main lobe within one bin (which is a motivation for flat-top windows) and is more difficult to calculate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, can I assume that the 2n-point fft is more accurate than the n-point fft?

No. The N-point FFT contains all independent information that is required to completely represent the spectrum.

> And how would that be considering that the 2n-point fft is just created from adding n zeros to the original signal and therefore doesn't add meaningful information to the signal?

Your reasoning is correct. Zero padding does not add information. It's just interpolation.

> And when applying ffts to signals that are not window functions: Am I generally better off just adding more points to the fft?

Depends on the application. Sometimes yes, sometimes no, but that really depends on what you want to do with the data.

This is priamrily a function of "visual intepretation". Let's look at a simple sine wave at a normalized frequency of $\pi/2$

$$x[n] = \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}n+\pi/4)$$

Here is a graph using a standard `plot()` function

[image]

This **looks** like a trapezoid wave but it **is** a true sine wave. The misconception is created by the `plot()` function which simply connects the individual samples with straight lines. That assumption is wrong and creates a substantial visual error. The correct way to draw this would be `sinc()` interpolation.

So interpolation can be quite useful especially if you want to actually look (with your eyes) at the data. However, mathematically it's not required. All the information is there.

Comment: Sounds to me like padding is generally sensible when trying to visually identify frequency components in a signal, rule of thumb being more padding is better. But padding is generally not sensible when using ffts to calculate transfer functions using the H1 or H2 estimator because the extra zeroes add no information to the cross and auto spectra calculation. Then again, if you wanted to visualize the transfer function, the interpolation may be useful. Can you think of a scenario where padding would actually do harm?

Comment: I can’t unless you’re *very* concerned with computational costs (*very very*)

Comment: [see also](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/22041/63763)

Comment: Memory costs might be more concerning, depending on your hardware and how much data you are analyzing. Depending on what you know about the system you are measuring, there is an optimization to be made for deciding how much to zero-pad, if at all. Knowing information a priori - number of potential sinusoids, how close they are to each other, are they only going to be at bin centers, etc. will define constraints for that optimization. [Here is a paper](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~abemoto/abe-aes04.pdf) that explores that optimization for parameter estimation.

Comment: yes, memory costs of course, good point!